# How do I use a series of quantities in a column of cells to populate set information for that many cells into another column?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm working with sensitive information, so I can't show too much, but I think my request will be clear.

I'm trying to use the below quantities to spit out values in a different sheet that number of times in order.
On one page I have quantities that vary based on input by user.
[quantity 11(first sheet cell K5) grey(first sheet cell L5), quantity 13(first sheet cell L6) black(first sheet cell K6), quantity 61(first sheet cell L7) orange(first sheet cell K7)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0AWT.png)
I need to turn these into exactly on the second sheet in the workbook:
11 instances of "Grey" and "70" in cells (C2-12) and (D2-12)
13 instances of "Black" and "70" in cells (C13-24) and (D13-24)
61 instances of "Orange" and "70 in cells (C25-86) and (D25-86)
and so on...
However, I need to be able to change the initial quantities and have the C and D columns reflect that change in quantity, in order.
[columns C and D with their variable inputs, with correct quantities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XlZ5.png)
I have attempted the following formula, which does what I need for column C, but I need each cell to do all three things so it can move the correct values up and down the column as needed.
This works for the grey value
=IF(A8<=Sheet1!$L$5,Sheet1!$K$5,"")
This works for the black value
=IF(A2<=Sheet1!$L$6+Sheet1!$L$5+Sheet1!$L$6,"")
This works for the orange value
=IF(A2<=Sheet1!$L$7+Sheet1!$L$5+Sheet1!$L$6,Sheet1!$K$7,"")
I need one formula that does checks L5, L6, and L7 in order.
I want to attach a proxy spreadsheet, which also included the changes I need to simulate from Sheet1 K and L rows 8 and 9, to also add to the end of the total on Sheet2 columns C and D. Unfortunately, I don't see a tool for attaching on this website.

Comment: I think you are trying to tackle a problem that is so much easier to solve in O365 Excel, that it justifies purchasing it if you're able.  This problem is a thousand times easier to solve using the newer array formulas that are available in O365.

Comment: Can you attach a sample sheet with  sample data.

Comment: @Max I am not able to purchase and use something different on this company computer I'm working on, but I may be able to find a computer that has better when I get to work tomorrow.  What would the process be at that point?

Comment: @ Blind Spots I will try to work up something to match without having the data I need to keep private.

Comment: @BlindSpots, please forgive a beginner question, but how do I attach my spreadsheet to this page?

Comment: @Max, I figured I can use all 3 formulas for the whole length in 3 new columns, then reference only the first column that has a value in it.  I just need to know how to reference the first value out of 3 columns, with blanks ignored.

Comment: This is solved. Below are the formulas used in columns C and D.
Column C:
=IF(A2<=SUM(Sheet1!$L$5:$L$5),"Grey",IF(A2<=SUM(Sheet1!$L$5:$L$6),"Black",IF(A2<=SUM(Sheet1!$L$5:$L$7),"Orange",IF(A2<=SUM(Sheet1!$L$5:$L$8),"29 Grey",IF(A2<=SUM(Sheet1!$L$5:$L$9),"23.30 Grey","")))))
Column D:
=IF(C2="23.30 Grey",23.3,IF(C2="29 Grey",29,IF(LEN(C2)>1,70,"")))